# How to translate **long_options option <offset aHelp, 0, 0, 68h>** into re-assemble code?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, elf, disassembly

Test platform is 32 bit Linux.

I use IDA Pro to disassembly the basename elf binary from coreutils.

In the data section I find this:

```
long_options    option <offset aHelp, 0, 0, 68h>
```

Could any one give some help on how to translate this into reassemble code?

Be more specific, nasm syntax reassemble code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried???  I am in a giving mood, this should get you started:

equates:

```
NULL                equ 0
no_argument         equ 0
required_argument   equ 1
optional_argument   equ 2
```

In the .data section:

```
long_options        dd  aHelp, no_argument, NULL, 68H, \
                        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

`getopt*` is documented, so is NASM.  RTFM!

Comment: Hi Gunner, Thank you for your answer... But I can not find getopt* in the [manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11/nasmdoc.pdf), which made me confused...